# Framer motion and React - create a loop animation doesn't work, error on "repeatType"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

I'm trying to create a loading animation with framer-motion in react (typescript).

Here is my variant;

```
const loadingCircleTransition = {
  duration: 0.8,
  repeat: Infinity,
  repeatType: 'loop',
  ease: 'easeInOut',
};
```

and here is how it is implemented in my jsx:

```
animateText.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <motion.span
              key={index}
              variants={loadingCircle}
              transition={loadingCircleTransition}
              ^^^^^^
             here is the issue
            >
              {item === ' ' ? ' - ' : item}
            </motion.span>
          );
        })
```

Typescript is complaining saying :

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"loop" | "reverse" | "mirror" | undefined'.ts(2322)

I don't understand what is wrong here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

{repeatType: 'loop'} is inferred as {repeatType:string}, have to inform the compiler that it is a literal type, you need to use the as const assertion.

```
const loadingCircleTransition = {
  duration: 0.8,
  repeat: Infinity,
  repeatType: "loop" as const,
  ease: "easeInOut",
};
```

Comment: woaw it was just that... thank you, not really related but it looks like it doesn't do the loop animation. My span doesn't return at the origin point smoothly